# Intuition behind regular points (Brownian motion)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

The following definition is from Karatzas/Shreve:

Consider the stopping time of the right-continuous filtration $\mathscr{F}_t$ given by $\sigma_D=\inf\{t >0 ;W_t \in D^c\}$ [$W_t$ is Brownian motion, $D$ is open and bounded]. We say that a point $a \in \partial D$ is regular for $D$ if $P^a(\sigma_D=0)=1$, i.e. a Brownian path started at $a$ does not immediately return to $D$.

I thought I understood this definition but obviously I am not: Let e.g. $D$ be the open unit ball. Why is now every boundary point of $D$ regular?! I mean if we start Brownian motion at the boundary, at $t=0$ it is clearly in $D^c$. It could then go either into $D$ or not. What is the (intuitive) reason that I will not go into $D$?

Comment: The Brownian motion will necessarily go into $D$, but will not stay there, this is the point.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks but this is not clear to me. Which property of BM ensures that it "will necessarily go into $D$"? And if it does, how does this fit to the above explanation that "a Brownian path started at a regular point does not immediately return to $D$" as it is given in the theorem?

Comment: I'm speaking of the unit ball $D$. In any right neighborhood of $0$, there will be infinitely many (even uncountable number) of points $t$ such that $W_t\in D^c$.  This follows from the fact that the signed distance to $\partial D$ behaves like the one-dimensional Brownian motion near the boundary. And the latter has no isolated zeros.

Comment: @zhoraster So with this argumentation the Brownian motion will also necessarily go into $D^c$ right? So one case does not exclude the other, i.e. we could have $P^a(\sigma_D =0)=1=P(\sigma_{D^c} =0)$?

Comment: Yes, precisely!